# session.CreateCriteria always returns zero record

Tags: nhibernate

I have a basic method that doesn't get any record from the database. In configuration it creates the table with no problem. It always returns zero record. I've added the configuration file below. I don't understand what is the problem.

```
   public List<Note> GetAll()
    {
        var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();

        var note = session.CreateCriteria<Note>().List<Note>();

        return note.ToList();
    }
```

Helper :

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                InitializeSessionFactory();
            }

            return _sessionFactory; 
        }
    }

    private static void InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                          .ConnectionString(
                              @"Server={server};Database=ToDo;
                                User ID=lorem;Password=lorem;
                                Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;")
                          .ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Note>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
            .Create(true, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. First activate the logging in nhibernate with this link : http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx
2. Lookup the output window for exceptions or another warnings if you can't find anything go to step 3.
3. Once you get the step 1 you can execute the raw sql sentence directly in Microsoft SQL Server Management Console or similar tool, perhaps the error is in class definition.

Comment: I actually no idea how it does. I use fluent nhibernate and i cannot a proper information how to enable that. But The problem is my n-tier structure. So when i gain domain,map and nhibernate helper in same tier, there is no problem. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: You got right with Fluent do this to activate the logging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033395/fluentnhibernate-support-for-sql-server-2008-r2/11035631#11035631)